# squid reverse proxy log

Tags: reverse-proxy, squid, log-files

we have an exchange server behind a squid reverse proxy
there is many failed account events in exchange, the exchange event viewer display the IP address of the reverse proxy as source address in addition of a source port

now, i'm trying to get hold of the real IP address of the client from squid log using the source port number given by exchange log event

i've modified squid logformat for the access.log to include <lp which stand as (Local port number of the last server or peer connection)
unfortunately this port doesn't match the exchange source port
i m sure about this fact because i've done packet capture for the flow between exchange and the squid reverse proxy, the port in the packet capture match the port in exchange log event, however it doesn't match the <lp parameter in the access.log

so i m stuck at this point
any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you looked into your firewall?